# Adjust the width of the container according children width when children are on multiline

Tags: html, css

I want some solution to adjust the width of the container according children width when children are on multiple lines. When children are on just single line then display:inline-block for the container element make what I need. But when they are on multiple lines, the container just behave the same like display:block.

Only two solutions what I know are:
1) Set container max-width as some multiplying of children width. But it is not a universal solution (I mean display on devices with lower resolution).

2) Use jQuery to compute the container width. but I'd rather like to use some pure HTML/CSS solution.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="wrapper1">     
    <div id="wrapper2">                
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>          
       <div class="el">
       </div>        
    </div>         
</div> 


  <div id="wrapper2">                
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>          
    <div class="el">
    </div>        
  </div>         
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper1{
  max-width:1200px;
  margin:auto;
}
#wrapper2{
  background: #FF0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.el{
  float:left;
  margin:10px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:#00F;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please test this:

```
#wrapper1{
display: -webkit-flex; 
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
display: flex;  
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper2{
max-width:880px;
display: -webkit-flex; 
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
display: flex;  
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
-webkit-justify-content: space-betweeen;
}
```

Here is a sample:
[Sample](http://drmjenab.com/index11.aspx#)

Click on start page and see the page after i think that is what you want.

Comment: Ok it seems great.

Comment: Flex box is very very useful especially in responsive designs. If you want read about, w3Scools is very good to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#wrapper1{
    width:1200px;
}
#wrapper2{
    display:inline-block;
}
.el{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#00F;
}
.ul{
    padding: 20px;
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper1">
  <div id="wrapper2">
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ul">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I find. I need keep same gaps betwen children and it must work on lower resolution. In your case the width of #wrapper1 is force set to 1200px. Actually I need some way to auto reduce the width of #wrapper2. In normal view it will have 1100px (5 elements on line which 200px width + 2* 10px margin). And ideally on smaller screen it will be 880px (4 elements on line), 660(3), 440(2), 220(1)

Comment: #wrapper1{
  max-width:1200px;
}
#wrapper2{
   width: auto;
  display:inline-block;
}